# Center a div to the page while inline with another div

Tags: css

I need to align an element to the center of the screen while having an element to the left of it.

I can achieve this with float left and setting the padding of the center element to match the width of the floated element. But, in this case I will not always know the width.

I do not know how better to explain this. Searchs have failed me.

Comment: There are many ways. please draw how should it be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `flex` to get the same [flex Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-1 {
  padding: 2%;
  background: tomato;
  flex: 0 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-1">1</div>
  <div class="box-1">2</div>
</div>
```